# Find the rectangle in an image containing certain text

Tags: python

[image]

Are there any python libraries or algorithm's to find a specified text's location in and image?

I tried using pytesseract to take a picture and scan if the word exist, and then slowly crop some of the image away until it would just be the text left. But it's a very tedious task and takes an immense amount of time for pytesseact to constantly process the text in the newly cropped image.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach to the problem though.

What the outcome should be is the (x1, y1, x2, y2) position of the yellow marked text in the picture.

Comment: Do you always want to find the text which is marked?

Comment: You mean `pytesseract`. As far as I know, your approach is correct, you must use a software for optical character recognition (OCR) like tesseract.

Comment: @terencehill yes pytesseract.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bounding box (`boundingRect`) of the `opencv` library .
Give a look to this tutorial:
[http://www.danvk.org/2015/01/07/finding-blocks-of-text-in-an-image-using-python-opencv-and-numpy.html][1]